# Splitting Strings And Printing Into Different Cells, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and have been cracking my head to solve this problem. I have a string of three characters which I want to split and place the values into an array in excel. So for instance,

```
Sub Splitdata()

Dim x As Variant
Dim txt As String

txt = "Today is sunny"
x = Split(txt)

Range("C1:C3").Value = x

End Sub
```

However this only returns the first character from the string in cells C1-c3 i.e. "Today". I imagine a loop is required, however I'm not sure how to make one yet. Is there also a general way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could simply solve your problem by changing your splitting line into this one:

```
x = Split(txt, " ")
```

Edit: and change the line which passes result to sheet into this:

```
Range("C1:C3").Value = Application.Transpose(x)
```

Comment: KazJaw, that still presents me with the same problem- The word "today" still shows up on C1,C2 and C3. I would like the whole string to be split up and each different value goes into a unique cell.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a 1-dimensional array to a range, by default it will go horizontally (so C1:E1 would work OK), not vertically.

However, you can use `Transpose()` to flip the array so it will populate a vertical range:

```
Range("C1:C3").Value=application.transpose(split("a b c"))
```