# Splitting cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I want to split cells in excel on last occurence of `:` (Colon) . For example `test:test1:test2` must be split into `test2` i.e., last occurence of `:`.

How can I do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting Strings And Printing Into Different Cells, Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138388/splitting-strings-and-printing-into-different-cells-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your substring after last `:` is less than 255 characters:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,":",REPT(" ",255)),255))
```

if your substring after last `:` could be longer than 255 characters:

```
=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-MATCH(2,1/(MID(B2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2))),1)=":")))
```

both formulas with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you do it like this with VBA WrdArray holds all the words and we use UBound to get the last one in the array.

```
Public Sub Spl()
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    Dim text_string As String
    text_string = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
    WrdArray() = Split(text_string, ":")
    x = WrdArray(UBound(WrdArray()))
    Sheet1.Cells(2, 3) = x
End Sub
```

Thanks to simoco for pointing out that the original function didn't work.

`=RIGHT(B2; SEARCH(":";B2;1))`

Comment: `SEARCH` finds _first_ occurance..what your formula returns for `t:test:test2`?

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own UDF which wraps `InstrRev`

```
Public Function InstrReverse(cell As Range, char As String) As Integer

InstrReverse = InstrRev(cell.Value, char)

End Function
```

Then (assuming your target string is in A1), this will give you the left part

```
=LEFT(A1,InstrReverse(A1,":")-1)
```

and this will give you the right part

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-InstrReverse(A1,":"))
```